# vbs script not working with loop and timeout

Tags: loops, vbscript

I made a simple vbs script to kill a process but need to loop it.

```js
Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


WScript.Sleep 5000


oShell.Run "taskkill /im firefox.exe", , True

loop
```

Comment: There is no `Do` for your `do ... loop` construct.

Comment: What is your terminating condition? You should be clear as to why you need to loop this segment of code.

Comment: i need to loop it cuz i have a program that start every 5 or 10 mints..i'ts like error box and want to kill it when it start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim oShell : Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do
    WScript.Sleep 5000
    oShell.Run "taskkill /im firefox.exe", , True
loop
```

Will kill firefox every 5 secs forever.